# "You belong to me" or "You belong with me"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

What's the difference between the titular expressions? if any, at all.

Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries could not help!!

Comment: "You belong to me" mostly reminds me of the song ["Button Up Your Overcoat "](https://youtu.be/6UliCMEdTFE).

Comment: @DavidK: Ooh, that's pleasant. "You belong to me" mostly reminds *me* of the song ["Every Breath You Take"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMOGaugKpzs), which is much darker.

Comment: @ruakh Oh, the Creepy Stalker Song. I remember that one too, though my mother definitely did _not_ sing it to me as a lullaby. I could see either of the phrases going that way, depending on context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The phrase "you belong to me" is an expression in English (at least American English) most often used in an address to a romantic partner. The phrase *[belong to](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/belong#belong)*, in this case, clearly conveys possessiveness

> (belong to) Be the property of:
>   *the vehicle did not belong to him*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

There is a bit of a chattel tone to the overall phrase, and may stem from a period when a man was seen as *owning* his wife and children (but not necessarily vice-versa). Such usage dates back to at least the early 19th century. In [The Ariel: A Literary Gazette](https://books.google.com/books?id=Lj4ZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA160&dq=%22you%20belong%20to%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZfVZVa7oLcKANuCrgYAC&ved=0CEUQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22you%20belong%20to%20me%22&f=false), in 1827 we find

> You are my betrothed wife, and as such, you belong to me alone!

However, in current marriage ceremonies in the US, the phrase *Do you **take** this [man/woman] ...?* is used bilaterally.

Another meaning of the phrase *[belong to](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/belong)* is a bit less possessive, but still obligatory

> (followed by to) to be bound to (a person, place, or club) by ties of affection, dependence, allegiance, or membership

*Collins*

The term *[belong with](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belong)* (or *belong in* or *at*) conveys aptness rather than ownership

> to be in a proper situation

*Merriam-Webster*

Both *you belong to me* and *you belong with me* convey that the speaker and the listener should be in a romantic relationship.  However, the former suggests that the relationship clearly exists, and he or she intends to maintain (or enforce) it. The latter suggest that it *should* be the case, and might be more likely heard as an entreaty rather than a statement of fact.

Comment: Let’s not forget those immortal words of Gina G: “I belong to you / And you, you belong to me”. Like _take_, it is perfectly commonplace nowadays for the _belong to_ relationship to go both ways. (And of course, both _belong to_ and _belong with_ are not **necessarily** about romantic relations. A tyrant may well say, “You all belong to me!”, and I would find it quite natural for someone to tell a family member that “I don’t want you to move. You belong here with me.”)

Answer (score 9):

The difference is huge.

"Belong to" means you treat the person as **your property**. (This may not go down well with your significant other.)

"Belong with" means you find it proper that you should **walk together**.

Comment: Walk together ?

Comment: Surely, depending on the conext, it could mean other things than "walk together"
If you told your significant other that they belong with you, surely you mean that you should be togther/live together?

Comment: You belong with me is the title of a famous Taylor Swift song, its kinda a romantic thing.

Comment: "You belong to me." doesn't imply that you are calling the other person your property, unless said in a specific context and tone. It can also be used as a term of endearment, just like on a Valentine's "Be Mine" or "You're mine".

Comment: [Citation needed]

Comment: @FarazMasroor Its kinda romantic in the stalkery "I know better than you" way.

Comment: I think it goes beyond "implying" ownership; it's unequivocal on the matter. What is a little more subjective and dependent on tone is whether or not that ownership should be considered romantic. Lot's of people are into that kind of thing if it's playful (or adorable on a teddy bear), but it could easily be sinister too.

I would describe _"You belong with me"_ as a sweeter, more innocent expression of a desire for intimacy.

Comment: @scarl3tt But I would be much more likely to say "You belong to me" than "You belong with me" to my children as an innocent expression of endearment. It's obvious from these comments that these phrases can be used in a variety of contexts to address a variety of people in varying states of relation. This answer addresses only 1 possible connotation for each phrase.

Answer (score 2):

They can have similar or even identical meanings in certain contexts, e.g.: a 'romantic' relationship with one particularly dominating partner.

Typically, though, "belong to" implies outright ownership (like a master owning a slave) while "belong with" suggests that the speaker feels that s/he and the person s/he is speaking to belong together.

It's probably not very politically correct to say either to your partner, though!

Comment: Who is politically correct with his partner? :O

Comment: Probably you heard the song "You belong with me".

Comment: @EiliaAbraham If you mean that the song is part of the context of your question, you might want to just edit it in - I doubt I'm the only one who hasn't heard it or didn't make the connection.

Comment: @Jefromi, No, it's not part of the context. I mentioned  the song in response to the **HerrPink** expression "It's probably not very politically correct to say either to your partner, though!" as a counter-example!

Answer (score 1):

It's funny how a single word can change the meaning.

"You belong to me": It has a sense of ownership in it, implying that the person or the thing that is being referred to is owned by you or is yours to keep.

"You belong with me": It has a lighter tone and a sense of opinion in it. that in your opinion, the person or the thing being referred to "SHOULD" be with you. but it is not a must.