# Why are we in love "with" someone?

Tags: etymology, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I'd like to learn the etymology of using the preposition *with* in the phrase *in love with somebody.* For me it doesn't make much sense because *with* seems to imply something that is shared by two people, something symmetrical wherein the phrase only states that one person has romantic feelings towards another. In Polish, we say *być zakochanym w kimś* which directly translates to *be in love in somebody,* which, at least to me, seems to make much more sense.

**Why do we use/What is the etymology of using *with* in the phrase *in love with somebody*?**

Comment: Interesting question. French too, doesn't use it. *Elle est amoureuse de Jean*.

Comment: May be (indirectly) related : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247077/you-belong-to-me-or-you-belong-with-me

Comment: We can also be in love 'with' an idea or an inanimate object and clearly that can't be reciprocated. The usage goes back a long way. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+love+with&year_start=1300&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20love%20with%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "With" seems to make perfect sense. Love is an emotion, and plenty of other emotions are paired with "with": I was angry with him, I'm not happy with her, he's frustrated with them, etc. "With" in all these cases seems to mean that there are two nouns and one is causing a particular emotion in the other.

Comment: @Nicole at the moment of asking this question I didn't realize there are quite so many situations where "with" is used with emotions and now I see that this question is not the question I should have ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This usage may well go back to Old English, which (ironically) uses "with" for feelings of opposition.  For the sense of "**with**" "after words of conduct or feeling towards (a person etc.)," the *OED* cites *King Alfred's Old English version of Boethius De consolatione philosophiae* from the  year 888:

> Hwi murc nast ðu **wið** min?

In a [modern translation](http://www.uky.edu/~kiernan/ENG720/SdgTrans/SedgefieldProseTrans.htm), "Why dost thou frown on me[?]" The Old English Translator translates "murc" to "dismal," so a more literal sense is "Why are you disapproving of me?"

The *[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229612?rskey=bo2kpG&result=2#eid)* notes that this sense of opposition for "with" was replaced by feelings of mutuality, and in Middle English, as the word took over the Old English *mid* (with, cognate of the Greek "meta"), it became idiomatic with the object of romantic feeling.

Comment: Very interesting, can you please provide a link to this semantic transformation of "with"?

Comment: @Josh61Would if I could.  All I have is paper for the *OED*.  It's under the history of "with" as a preposition.

Comment: Link that If you can , it may be useful to users.

Comment: @Josh61 OED online brings it up on single-word query.  Linked in answer.

Comment: I am marking this answer as correct because it seems to fit best, although  after some comments in other answers I realize that this is not question I wanted to ask. Would you mind adding that "with" is also used with a lot other *feeling* verbs and love is not an exception?

Comment: @Maurycy Which question did you want to ask?

Comment: One thing I didn't realize is that "with" is also used with a lot of other feeling-related verbs so now I'd want to ask "Was there a time when 'with' was not used with feeling-related verbs?" or something along these lines.

Comment: As the *OED* documents, "with" has been with us for oppositional feelings since Old English and came to be used for other mutual feelings in Middle English.  It's not used with "hate," "like," "fond", or "dislike" today, but it is with "disgust," "pleased," "angry," and "annoyed."  I'd guess the disparities could be traced to the case used for the verbs' objects, but that would take someone with more expertise than I have.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=love) the expression dates back to the 16th century:

> - To ***fall in love*** is attested from early 15c. ***To be in love with (someone) is from c. 1500***.

- I think that it is derived from the earlier expression ***fall in love*** where the preposition ***with*** may result  more natural to use.

Answer (score -1):

Why not "with"? What preposition would you suggest?  Different languages have quite different prepositions: German verliebt in, French amoureux de, English in love with.  I wouldn't rack my brains about the preposition, it's more or less idiomatic.

Comment: I am afraid the best explanation I can give for asking is already present in the body of the question.

Comment: You are used to "in" from earliest age, so you find it natural. This will be true for speakers of other languages, too.

Comment: Partially, yes. But as I said "with" gives the impression of being a bi-directional association, at least for me, because if A is with B, then B is automatically with A. And it's not the same with "in" which is uni-directional - when A is in B it does not mean that B is in A. But it doesn't necessarily have to be "in", it could be "over", "on" or even "to". That's my main issue.

Comment: I don't think "with" in this kind of construction implies symmetry. You can be angry with someone, satisfied with them, frustrated with them, in love with them, upset with them, and none of these imply that the other person shares your feeling. I agree that it would make a lot of sense for "with" to imply symmetry, so that to be X with a person means that you and they are both X and that your Xness is somehow shared with theirs, but in fact it doesn't.

Comment: (In cases where X is a verb rather than "be + adjective", "with" does work that way. To rejoice or grieve with someone, for instance, means to do it together with them.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Indeed, the idiomatic verb construct mentioned by the OP, "fall in love with", is probably more symmetric than most (since it's strongly tied with the concept of "sharing love with" someone).  I would conjecture that many such constructs are sufficiently similar to constructs where "with" would be literal (e.g. have a bone to pick with someone implies wanting to involve the other person in discussion; being upset with someone would not, but it has sufficiently similar meaning that "with" could evolve to cover the latter usage as well as the former).

Comment: I suppose it might be then that the Polish equivalent of this preposition is pretty much exclusively symmetrical and thus I project my experiences from my native tongue to English making it a kind of false friend for me.